# In CMake, specify all executables target_link_libraries certain libraries

Tags: c++, c, cmake

In CMake, is there a way to specify that all my executables links to some library?  Basically I want all my executables link to tcmalloc and profiler.  Simply specify -ltcmalloc and -lprofiler is not a good solution because I want to let CMake find the paths to the library in a portable way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the built-in `add_executable` function with your own which always adds the required link dependencies:

```
macro (add_executable _name)
    # invoke built-in add_executable
    _add_executable(${ARGV})
    if (TARGET ${_name})
        target_link_libraries(${_name} tcmalloc profiler)
    endif()
endmacro()
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could override the built-in commands.  Good to know.

Comment: I just read in the `tcmalloc` documentation that it *must* come at the end of the linker list, and just specifying the dependency with `target_link_libraries` does not guarantee that condition. If it is not at the end of the link list, then there will be false leak reports.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function/macro in CMake that does the work for you.

```
function(setup name sources
add_executable(name sources)
target_link_library(name tcmalloc profiler)
endfunction(setup)
setup(foo foo.c)
setup(bar bar.c)
```

Check out [the documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afunction) for more information.

Comment: It works, but kind of hacky.  I need to replace every `add_executable` with `setup`.  Is there some variable that I can set globally to achieve this?

Comment: You can modify the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS variable (check CMakeCache.txt in your build directory).  Personally I'd say that's more of a hack than switching to a function, but if you have a significant number of executables in your project that's the faster solution.